# iOS redirect to specific password reset page?

Tags: ios, safari, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari

We've had the following iOS message appear when logging in to our website:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a file we can place into our website's root folder to tell iOS to redirect to the following exact URL rather than just our homepage when a user taps on **Change Password on Website**?

[www.example.com/pages/reset-password/](http://www.example.com/pages/reset-password/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it is by setting up a `/.well-known/change-password` redirect on your server to your actual password reset page.

Using your example, create a redirect from `https://www.example.com/.well-known/change-password` to `https://www.example.com/pages/reset-password/` That's it. For the redirection, use the HTTP status code 302 Found, 303 See Other or 307 Temporary Redirect.

Alternatively, you could serve an HTML page at `/.well-known/change-password` with a `<meta>` tag using an `http-equiv="refresh"`.

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.example.com/pages/reset-password/">
```

The redirect is supported in Safari and Chromium-based browsers, and there's a [W3C spec](https://wicg.github.io/change-password-url/) that defines the behavior. More details in https://web.dev/change-password-url/