# react to iCloud keychain message "Password compromised" in react-native app with Firebase Deeplink

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, deep-linking, keychain

I have a react-native app with FireBase deeplinks for several cases.
Now I've found that on iOS 14+ users can have a message after login that their password (used from the iOS keychain) is compromised and they show change it.
So far so good, but then iOS is presenting them a popover with the message "Change password on website"
When a customer follows that link, my app runs dead on a unknown FireBase Deeplink.

How to react on this situation? Where to configure the link customers can follow when this message pops? Can't find the docs for this situation.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/q/65949390/1271826 answer your question?